# Store/keep second minimum value in group_by & summarise using Dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe with data such as here

```
library(dplyr)
data <- structure(list(State = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 
.Label = c("AK", "RI"), class = "factor"), 
Company = structure(1:8, .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H"), class = "factor"), 
Employees = c(82L,104L, 37L, 24L, 19L, 118L, 88L, 42L)), 
.Names = c("State", "Company", "Employees"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

My goal is to group each state (By the state column,) collect the number occurrences of each, and collect the *second minimum* value of employees for each group.

Using dplyr I've been able to create this,

```
data <- data %>% group_by(State) %>% summarise(count = n(), min.employees = min(Employees))
```

which returns the *minimum* value. However, I have been unable to find a way to return the second minimum value.

I can provide more info if need be,

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `nth` to select `n`th value ordered by `Employees`.

```
library(dplyr)

data %>% 
  group_by(State) %>% 
  summarise(count = n(), 
            min.employees = nth(Employees, 2, order_by = Employees))

# A tibble: 2 x 3
  State count min.employees
  <fct> <int>         <int>
1 AK        4            37
2 RI        4            42
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. You can arrange by `State` and `Employees` and then extract the second minimum. Here the code:

```
library(dplyr)
#Code
data %>% 
  arrange(State,Employees) %>%
  group_by(State) %>%
  summarise(Count=n(),Value=Employees[2])
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  State Count Value
  <fct> <int> <int>
1 AK        4    37
2 RI        4    42
```